# How do I get one junit report from TestNG for all my test cases?

Tags: java, junit, testng

I have a TestNG xml file formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
<parameter name="remoteOrLocal" value="local" />
<parameter name="environment" value="####" />
<parameter name="remoteAddress" value="0.0.0.0" />
<test name="1" >
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.Test1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="2">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.Test2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="3">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.Test3"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite
```

But I use a test case management tool that requires junit output which shouldn't be a problem since TestNG generates junit output automatically.

**The problem is this:**
In the directory under test-output called junitreports, there is one junit report for each class in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter -->
<testsuite hostname="fadavis-HP-EliteBook-8470p" name="tests.Test1" tests="3" failures="1" timestamp="15 May 2015 19:25:12 GMT" time="0.023" errors="1">
  <testcase name="method1" time="0.012" classname="tests.Test1"/>
  <testcase name="method3" time="0.004" classname="tests.Test1"/>
  <testcase name="method2" time="0.007" classname="tests.Test1">
    <error type="java.lang.AssertionError" message="null">
      <![CDATA[java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:101)
    at tests.Test1.method2(Test1.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]>
    </error>
  </testcase> <!-- method2 -->
</testsuite> <!-- tests.Test1 -->
```

where the suite name is the same as the classname.  How can I get just one Junit report file with the results from a suite of TestNG tests?

Answer (score 2):

There should be directory called `MySuite` on same level as `junitreports` (basically name from your `<suite name="MySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">`) and inside is one XML for all tests.

This is generated by `org.testng.reporters.JUnitXMLReporter` if it's not there, try to add this reporter to your listeners.

Comment: The files under MySuite are JUnit format, but there's still one per testcase and not one for the whole suite.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong to make it do that.

Comment: Yes, there is xml file for each `<test name="1">` so for your example there should be `1.xml, 2.xml and 3.xml`. If you want one xml file you can merge `tests` in testng.xml or you can implement own listener which generates one xml file from test suite.